# How to fetch the value from string in java

Tags: java

I am having a string in java like

```
{"status":200,"code":1,"reason":"SUCCESS","message":"Success","result":"{\"app_id\":\"vc\",\"subject.id\":\"test\",\"verb\":\"rock\",\"objects\":[{\"name\":\"nil\",\"properties\":{\"name\":\"rockstar\",\"value\":\"34\"},\"date\":\"2013-09-25\"}]}"}
```

I have to get the "value" field in some string (i.e.34) and also the "name" filed (i.e rockstar) how to get that value in java.

Can this be done using the convert srting into json or like that.

Answer (score 0):

This string *is* JSON. Use a JSON parser like Jackson or Gson to turn it into a `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gson from Google. You can get it [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSONObject.java from http://json.org/java/

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(yourJsonString);
int code = obj.getInt("code");
String result = obj.getString("result");
...
```

Comment: JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(yourJsonString); it says that constructor is not defined